# Core Graphics the "true looking glass" approach advice is needed

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uikit, core-graphics

I have files with three resolutions of the same page artwork - standard, retina and double retina. The original artwork is very detailed and I'd like to create a looking glass to allow the users to see all the details.

- a pan with two fingers over the page background image will display looking glass image
- instead of simply zooming 2 x underlying background image part, it should display at the glass part the same  physical area from another file with the next bigger resolution.

I'm trying to put together many examples I've found so far, but i see so many ways to do that! Could you please share with me the most optimal way of how would you approach this problem from the Core Graphics point of view? The key is speed!

My plan is

- detect two finger pan gesture (the single finger pan is reserved to page curl)
- move UIImageView with looking glass artwork to the new coordinates
- pass coordinates to the Core Graphic function
- detect which resolution file to use (retina device or not)
- construct a path and cut out the round part from the higher resolution image file
- apply the glass effect to it
- pass it back as byte array
- display it in the new View over the looking glass artwork

Am I freaking everything out here?